# How can I get crossproduct of two vectors like this?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to try crossproduct of two vectors `a` and `b`. I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
    $ \bigl[\vv{a},\vv{b}\bigr] $ \quad  $ \bigg[\vv{b},\vv{a}\bigg] $ \quad 
    $ \big[\vv{a},\vv{b}\big] $. 
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

How can I get like this?

[image]

Comment: The standard notation for cross product is `$a\times b$` or `$a\wedge b$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a dedicated macro called, say `\crprod`, with the help of the `mathtools` package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` directive -- and let the height of the square brackets vary depending on the what's in the argument of `\crprod` with the help of optional arguments such as `\big` or `\Big`.

A major advantage of this approach is that if you one day decide that you would rather employ, say, angle brackets than square brackets to denote cross products, all you would have to change is the definition of `\crprod` in the preamble, from

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\crprod}{\lbrack}{\rbrack}
```

to

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\crprod}{\langle}{\rangle}
```

---

For the case at hand, either `\crprod[\big]{ \vv{b},\vv{a}}` or `\crprod[\Big]{ \vv{a},\vv{b}}` would appear to be fine. In contrast, the square brackets produced by `\crprod[\bigg]{ \vv{a},\vv{b}}` would appear to be much too tall.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for  \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\crprod}{\lbrack}{\rbrack}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}
\[
    \crprod{ \vv{a},\vv{b}}        \quad
    \crprod[\big]{ \vv{b},\vv{a}}  \quad  
    \crprod[\Big]{ \vv{a},\vv{b}}  \quad 
    \crprod[\bigg]{\vv{b},\vv{a}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

By use of the `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}
     $\begin{bmatrix}\vv{a},\vv{b}\end{bmatrix}$   
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
If writing `\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}` is too long or too boring, you can define new command for cross product, for example `\cp`:

```
\newcommand\cp[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}
```

and then write

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\cp[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
some text $\cp{\vv{a},\vv{b}}$ in paragraph
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before:

[image]

Comment: bracket at below is too low.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter, bracket are always symmetrical.  Sorry.

Comment: Now, I know this. Thank you very much.